# Java hardcoded switch vs hashmap

Tags: java, performance, hashmap

Some Message class is able to return a tag name based on tag number
Since this class is instanciated many times, I am a bit reluctant to create a HashMap for each instance:

```
public class Message {
  private HashMap<Integer,String> tagMap;

  public Message() {
    this.tagMap = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
    this.tagMap.put( 1, "tag1Name");
    this.tagMap.put( 2, "tag2Name");
    this.tagMap.put( 3, "tag3Name");
  }

  public String getTagName( int tagNumber) {
    return this.tagMap.get( tagNumber);
  }
}
```

In favor of hardcoding:

```
public class Message {
  public Message() {
  }

  public String getTagName( int tagNumber) {
    switch( tagNumber) {
      case 1: return "tag1Name";
      case 2: return "tag2Name";
      case 3: return "tag3Name";
      default return null;
    }
  }
}
```

When you put everything in the mix ( Memory, Performance, GC, ...)
**Is there any reason to stick to HashMap?**

Comment: Would this not be the sort of situation where an `enum` would be ideal?

Comment: If the list is the same for all you messages, you could also make the map static.

Comment: Also, did you (by profiling) determine that the instantiation of the class is really an issue?

Comment: enum would not fit since some tags numbers may be unknown

Comment: If the map is static, what happens with subsequent calls to put()?

Comment: @AknownImous Nothing special, the new values just get added to the map...

Comment: How will this answer your 'i don't know all the tagNumbers up front' issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Initialize `MAP` in a static block.

And since you will be creating many objects of Message.you should write code like this

```
public class Message {

  private static HashMap tagMap;

  static {
     tagMap = new HashMap();
     tagMap.put( 1, "tag1Name");
     tagMap.put( 2, "tag2Name");
     tagMap.put( 3, "tag3Name");
  }

  public Message() {

  }

  public String getTagName( int tagNumber) {
    return tagMap.get( tagNumber);
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't know about calling put() in static blocks. Sweet

Comment: Using a Map cannot be faster than using a switch, this makes no sense.

Comment: @Byter is there any proof that a Map (and also what implementation of Map) is faster then a switch? Did you actually test this?

Comment: @Byter:A `HashMap` is `O(1)` (at best) but why is it faster construct than a `switch`?The `switch` is a branch instruction.It is not possible to be slower than a collection's function

Comment: sorry about that...Map enables us to write neat code.There is not much time difference between using a Map and a Switch.

Comment: @JamesB: Why is a static initialization block bad and what is the alternative here?

Comment: @Byter Really? Not much difference? :) From a branch prediction point of view a switch is REALLY bad and a TreeMap is way faster.

Comment: @Eugene http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931890/what-is-more-efficient-a-switch-case-or-an-stdmap

Comment: @JamesB i still didnt get why using static block is such a Bad thing??

Comment: @Byter your giving reference to a C++ question? :) Really? This conversation is useless. P.S. Read the second paragraph from the second answer by the way. ;)

Comment: @joergl I prefer not to use them. There is usually always an alternative as demonstrated by the numerous responses here. Plus, you normally have to write extra code to handle them when unit testing. Just my opinion.

Comment: You might even want to add

     `tagMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(tagMap);`

Only if the map won't change during runtime after the static block of course.

Answer (score 1):

Map can be used as command pattern in which key represents condition and value represents command to be executed the only drawback is object gets created before used so if you have large number of such conditions then you can opt for map else `switch` is always elegant approach if your conditions are few.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you need. For example if you ever needed to get all the tag names for display using a `Map` would pay off. Additionally if you replaced with a `TreeMap` you could get them sorted.
If you don't have such a need, then using a `Map` would be an overhead and your approach or an `Enum` would be much more efficient (you will have less readability though than you option of 5-10-20 `case` options)

Answer (score 0):

Why not make the getTagName method static and lazy load it from a properties file?

```
public static String getTagName(int tagNumber) {
    if tagsByID == null) {
        // load tags from properties
    }
    return tagsByID.get(tagNumber);
}
```

Easy to test and configurable without a recompile.

Comment: Properties files mean extra deliverables. Since the list is rather static, I would rather embed the mapping.

Answer (score 0):

If all your tag values are consecutive in the interval `[1..n]` then you can use an array or maybe an `ArrayList` and have direct access to the values.

```
public class Message {
    private ArrayList<String> tags;

    public Message() {
        this.tags =  = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.tags.add("Unknown");
        this.tags.add("tag1Name");
        this.tags.add("tag2Name");
        this.tags.add("tag3Name");
    }

    public String getTagName(int tagNumber) {
        return this.tags.get(tagNumber);
    }
}
```

Alternative with an array.

```
public class Message {
    private static final String[] tags = {
        "N/A",
        "tag1Name",
        "tag2Name",
        "tag3Name",
        null,
        null,
        "tag6Name",
    };

    public Message() {
    }


    public String getTagName(int tagNumber) {
        if (tagNumber < 0 || tagNumber > tags.length) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        return tags[tagNumber];
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not a contiguous list

Comment: @AknownImous Too bad. But I will let my answer remain anyway.

Comment: @AknownImous Do you have any idea how the tags are numbered? Maybe you can allow some gaps in an array without it taking too much memory anyway.