# Returning string constants in switch-case block with std::string

Tags: c++, c++14

NOTE: This is *not* about using a string for choosing the execution path in a switch-case block.

A common pattern in C++ is to use a switch-case block for converting integer constants to strings. This looks like:

```
char const * to_string(codes code)
{
    switch (code)
    {
        case codes::foo: return "foo";
        case codes::bar: return "bar";
    }
}
```

However, we are in C++, so using std::string is more appropriate:

```
std::string to_string(codes code)
{
    switch (code)
    {
        case codes::foo: return "foo";
        case codes::bar: return "bar";
    }
}
```

This however copies the string literal. Perhaps a better approach would be instead:

```
std::string const & to_string(codes code)
{
    switch (code)
    {
        case codes::foo: { static std::string str = "foo"; return str; }
        case codes::bar: { static std::string str = "bar"; return str; }
    }
}
```

But this is kinda ugly, and involves more boilerplate.

What is considered the cleanest and most efficient solution for this problem using C++14?

Comment: A private  hashmap with codes as key and string as value? A function to return the value based on the key.

Comment: "we are in C++, so using `std::string` is more appropriate" Says who? `std::string` is an owning mutable container, and you're returning an immutable, static value. What's wrong with `char const*`? In C++17, you have `std::string_view`, which you can implement for yourself without too much effort

Comment: @SamerTufail, thank you for validating me. I do this at work all the time. :) But was always curious if that is a good way to do things.

Comment: `std::string` adds semantics that are quite useful, like being able to query the string length without iterating over the character array. As for implementing `string_view`, I agree this would be useful, but stuff like this is generally frowned upon in this project (I am not the lead developer there).

Comment: @Joey Mallone why wouldnt it be? What makes you think its not the correct way to do things?

Comment: @SamerTufail, self-doubt.

Comment: @JoeyMallone https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931890/what-is-more-efficient-a-switch-case-or-an-stdmap   Allow me to "unvalidate" you for some cases :)

Comment: @UKMonkey, good to know. :)

Comment: Don't overthink this. You'll be hard pressed to find a more efficient method than to just return the string literal into the string. As a rule, don't return a string_view. It's like returning a reference. In this case it will work, but it forces a code reviewer to check your code to check. Write for simplicity and clarity. If you want to speed things up, measure.

Comment: Do note that with the last code block, static initialization comes with a performance penalty because it needs to be thread safe and checked every time the function is called.  That can out weigh the cost of a copy.

Comment: Relevant: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/14309/conversion-between-enum-and-string-in-c-class-header/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> This however copies the string literal.

Yes and no. It will copy the string literal indeed, but don't necessarily allocate memory. Check your implementation SSO limit.

---

You could use `std::string_view`:

```
constexpr std::string_view to_string(codes code) {
    switch (code) {
        case codes::foo: return "foo";
        case codes::bar: return "bar";
    }
}
```

You can find many backported versions like [this one](https://github.com/martinmoene/string-view-lite)

However, sometimes a `char const*` is the right abstraction. For example, if you were to forward that string into an API that require a null terminated string, you'd be better off returning it a c style string.

Comment: This. A `string_view` has value for sure, but otherwise I'd just stick with the original code. Certainly there's no reason to use a `string` just because we're writing C++. C++ still has `const char*`.

Answer (score 2):

> But this is kinda ugly, and involves more boilerplate.
>
> What is considered the cleanest and most efficient solution for this problem using C++14?

To answer the above, as @SamerTufail pointed out (and as I do it myself at work also), I would use `enum`s and `std::map` like this.

```
   typedef enum {
        foo = 1,
        bar = 2,
    } Key;

std::map<Key, std::string> hash_map = { {Key::foo ,"foo"}, { Key::bar,"bar"} };
```

And then in main() you could get the value like this,

```
std::cout << hash_map.find(Key::foo)->second;
```

I would create a function for returning the `second`, where you would check the iterator for `end()`, otherwise the interator would be invalid and using it would be UB.

---

**EDIT:** As others have pointed out in the comments and as per this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196995/is-there-any-advantage-of-using-map-over-unordered-map-in-case-of-trivial-keys), you could replace `std::map`, with `std::unordered_map` provided you do not need to keep elements in order.

And as per my experience, I always create such maps as `static const`. Therefore create them one time and use them many times to *amortize* the cost of creation.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot, I agree but if the map is static and created only once, the cost of using it is amortized over the lifetime of the program. No?

Comment: Yes, true. It would avoid copying and linear seach.

Comment: Not rather `std::unordered_map`?

Comment: What's that kind of typedef syntax? GCC refuses to compile even with `-std=c++17`...

Comment: @Aconcagua, I didn't know about `unordered_map`. Saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196995/is-there-any-advantage-of-using-map-over-unordered-map-in-case-of-trivial-keys) after your comment. Yes, probably `unordered_map` is a better option.

Comment: @Aconcagua, I removed the `typedef`. p.s. I don't even have `C++11`. I can't even initialize that map with the initializer list. So I use static functions to initialize and typedefs to avoid re-typing in 3 different places. Sorry for that.

Comment: Why not unordered_map? Which is what I meant by a hash map

Comment: I suspect that `N` would need to be surprisingly large for a linear  search of a `std::vector<std::pair<Key::foo, std::string>>` to be slower than using either a `unordered_map` or `map`.   Clang and recent GCC's can optimise it away to almost nothing, with no initial memory allocation, and all in contiguous memory.  Both maps have a memory allocation per node, dislocated from the main data structure, and both will use a disproportionate amount of memory to the (small) strings.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you eventually want a `std::string` with the label in it, the question is whether to create them:

1: in `to_string()`
2: in its caller

Using [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/FZM4Dl) it's pretty easy to find out.

Turns out (with recent compilers) that there's not a lot difference between the two.  Returning `const char *` has a slight edge on `std::string`

#### 1:

```
#include <string> 

char const * to_string(int code)
{
    switch (code)
    {
        case 0: return "foo";
        case 1: return "bar";
    }
}

std::string foo(int x)
{
    std::string s{to_string(x)};
    return s;    
}
```

#### 2:

```
#include <string> 

std::string to_string2(int code)
{
    switch (code)
    {
        case 0: return "foo";
        case 1: return "bar";
    }
}


std::string foo2(int x)
{
    std::string s{to_string2(x)};
    return s;    
}
```

Note:

- I needed to add `foo()` in order to stop the compiler optimising even more heavily....
- In both cases, the strings are short and can use the short-string optimisation.  Both clang and GCC have managed a *heap-elision*.  This is seriously impressive - the compiler knows that `to_string()` never returns a string bigger than 4   bytes long and then eliminates the code that would dynamically allocate heap memory.

The conclusion seems to be that writing natural, and tidy code has little performance penalty.